# How to derive the adjoint action ${\rm ad}_X(Y)=[X,Y]$ on the algebra from the adjoint transformation ${\rm Ad}$ of the Lie group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a problem deriving the adjoint action $ad_X(Y)=XY-YX$ from the adjoint transformation of the group on the Lie algebra.

**Background:**

The adjoint action of the Lie algebra on itself is given by the differential of the adjoint action of the Lie group on the Lie algebra.

Let $\gamma(t)$ be a curve through some element $g\in G$ on the manifold $G$ with $\gamma(0)=e \in G$ and tangent vector $\gamma'(0)=X \in T_eG$. We write the adjoint action

$Ad_g (X)= \underbrace{g}_{\in G} \underbrace{X}_{\in T_eG} \underbrace{g^{-1}}_{\in G}$ as  $Ad_g (Y)= Ad_{\gamma(t)}(Y) = \gamma(t) Y \gamma(t)^{-1}  $

**Problem**

My problem is calculating the differential at the identity

$ ad_X(Y)=\frac{d}{dt} Ad_{\gamma(t)}(Y) \big |_{t=0}= \frac{d}{dt} \gamma(t) Y \gamma(t)^{-1} \big |_{t=0} = \gamma'(0) Y \gamma(0)^{-1} +  \gamma(0)  Y  \frac{d}{dt}  \gamma(t)^{-1} \big |_{t=0} $

For example in "Fulton Harris - Representation Theory" the last step is calculated as

$ ad_X(Y)=\frac{d}{dt} Ad_{\gamma(t)}(Y) \big |_{t=0}= \frac{d}{dt} \gamma(t) Y \gamma(t)^{-1} \big |_{t=0} =  \gamma'(0) Y \gamma(0)^{-1} +  \gamma'(0) Y (-\gamma(0)^{-1}  \gamma'(0) \gamma(0)^{-1})  $ and therefore $ad_x=XY-YX$

can someone explain this last step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you write probably makes sense only for matrix Lie groups and algebras: 
the last term
$\gamma'(0) Y (-\gamma(0)^{-1}  \gamma'(0) \gamma(0)^{-1})$ should probably be
$\gamma(0) Y (-\gamma(0)^{-1}  \gamma'(0) \gamma(0)^{-1})$.

Then the rest follows from the matrix identity
$$\frac{d}{dt} A^{-1}(t)=-A^{-1}(t) \big(\frac{d}{dt} A(t)\big) \,A^{-1}(t)$$
which easilly follows from $\frac{d}{dt} \big(A(t)\,A^{-1}(t)\big)=0$.

Comment: One should add that, by Ado's theorem, every finite-dimensional Lie algebra has a faithful matrix representation.