# Getting from $\text{Int}(x)$ to $\text{Ad}(x)$ explicitely

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra.

If $$\text{Int}(x):G\to G,\text{Int}(x)(y)=xyx^{-1}$$
derives to
$$\text{Ad}(x):\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g},$$
how do I compute $\text{Ad}(x)(\mathbf{x})$ for $\mathbf{x}\in\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: What are $G$ and $\mathfrak{g}$? I'm guessing that $G$ is a Lie group, and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra!

Comment: Hi Mercy King, apologies for that, this has been added.

Answer (score 1):

Let ${\rm Inn}_A(B)=ABA^{-1}$. Here "Inn" stands for "inner". Then 
the map $${\rm Inn} :G→GL(G) ; A\mapsto {\rm Inn}_A$$
 is an homomorphism sending $A ∈ G$ to an automorphism on $G$.
Differentiating with respect to the second argument, we get a map
$$
Ad=d{\rm Inn}_e :G→GL(g) ;\quad  A\mapsto Ad_A
$$
 This map sends $A ∈ G$ to an automorphism on $\mathfrak{g}={\rm Lie}(G)$:
$$
Ad_A :\mathfrak{g}→ \mathfrak{g} ;\quad  Ad_A(X)=AXA^{−1}.
$$
For further details see other posts at MSE about this question, e.g.,

[Adjoint Lie algebra homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854105/adjoint-lie-algebra-homomorphism?rq=1)